# The word for referring to the patient's standard measurements such as heartbeat rate, blood pressure, etc

Tags: vocabulary

What is the word for referring to the patient's standard measurements (like heartbeat, blood pressure, etc)?

Comment: Are you thinking of *vital signs*?

Comment: Or possibly *biometrics*.

Comment: A simple web search on "heartbeat blood pressure temperature" turns up *vital signs*.

Comment: Consider "*vital parameters*". *Vital data* may also be monitored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These base statistics about a living organism are collectively referred to as Vital Signs. 
Or "Vitals"  for short.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vital_signs

Each of the examples you list is itself a "primary vital sign".